# scrolling bug in navigationbar sencha touch 2

Tags: extjs, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

I am use `navigationviev` with some buttons in `navigationBar`. I set navigationBar's property `scrollable` to '`horizontal`'. I can grab and move scrollbar line but the buttons still stay on same positions. How to fix this bug?

[image: scrollable bug]

source:

```
Ext.define('Example.view.Main', {
extend: 'Ext.NavigationView',
config: {
    fullscreen: true,
    styleHtmlContent: true,
    navigationBar: {
        scrollable: 'horizontal',
        items: [
            {
                xtype: 'button',
                text: 'btn1'
            },
            {
                xtype: 'button',
                text: 'btn2'
            },
            {
                xtype: 'button',
                text: 'btn3'
            },
            {
                xtype: 'button',
                text: 'btn4'
            },
            {
                xtype: 'button',
                text: 'btn5'
            },
            {
                xtype: 'button',
                text: 'btn6'
            }
        ]
    },
    items: [
        {
            xtype: 'panel',
            styleHtmlContent: true,
            html: '<h1>Hello!</h1>'
        }
    ]
}
```

});

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think adding too much button on navigation bar is good idea and Also I am not sure it's possible to make navigation bar scrollable.

Instead i suggest you to try following style

[Slide navigation with Sencha Touch](http://innofied.com/simplest-slide-navigation-with-sencha-touch-2-2/)

OR

[Facebook Style Navigation for Sencha Touch 2.1.1](http://senchatouchdev.com/wordpress/2013/02/25/facebook-style-navigation-for-sencha-touch-2-1-1/)

OR

[This one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16353827/sencha-touch-how-to-make-navigation-like-touch-theming-example-by-sencha-touch)

Comment: I sloved this task by creation of my own `navigationbar` with `toolbar` component on top insted of `titlebar` component in original `navigationbar`, but you are damn right, this was a bad idea